# Characters of SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})

Tags: sage, gap-system

I need to have description of all the characters of group $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z})$. I am implementing the following code on Sage online (changing the language to GAP).

```
\gap> g := SL(2, Integers mod 8);
gap> c := CharacterTable(g);
gap> Display(c);
```

But its giving me the many errors. How to fix this?

Comment: What kind of errors you get? I get results back from your code https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLV7CyVQj20TDSUfDMK0lNTy0qVsjNT1Gw0LTm5UoGSTpnJBYlJpekFoUkJuWkaqSDJFwyiwtyEis1kjWtAWWqEzY=&lang=gap&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Comment: Now it worked, thanks! I am new to using GAP. Do you know what is the syntax if I want to print all characters of dimension 3, say?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know. I am new as well.

Comment: @dragoboy works perfectly for me in my local installation of GAP 4.12.2 of 2022-12-18. We really need to know what those error messages say.